# batch file to Run on multiple servers

Tags: batch-file

I have a set of commands for which I have created batch file. Now I have to run those for around 100 servers.

How to do that?

I do not want to use powershell since the commands are not working on it.

Here is my `idrac6.bat` content:

```
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 config -g cfgipmilan -o cfgipmilanalertenable 1
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 config -g cfgIpmiLan -o cfgIpmiPetCommunityName WP!OME@Ro

racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.System.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.System.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Storage.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Storage.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Updates.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Updates.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Config.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Config.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Worknotes.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Worknotes.Warning -a none -n snmp

racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 set idrac.snmp.alert.1.enable 1
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 set idrac.snmp.alert.1.destaddr %4

racadm set idrac.snmp.trapformat V2
```

For a single server IP I user below command to execute.

```
idrac6.bat <Server IP> username password > idrac6732018.txt
```

Now I need to pass the whole list of servers IP's in `<Server IP>` field.

Comment: I've fixed your formatting, please delete the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If your server IP addresses are one per line in a text file along side the batch file then possibly the following implementation would help:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In (%1) Do Call :Sub %%A %2 %3 %4
Exit /B

:Sub
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 config -g cfgipmilan -o cfgipmilanalertenable 1
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 config -g cfgIpmiLan -o cfgIpmiPetCommunityName WP!OME@Ro

racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.System.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.System.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Storage.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Storage.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Updates.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Updates.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Config.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Config.Warning -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Worknotes.critical -a none -n snmp
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.Worknotes.Warning -a none -n snmp

racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 set idrac.snmp.alert.1.enable 1
racadm -r %1 -u %2 -p %3 set idrac.snmp.alert.1.destaddr %4

racadm set idrac.snmp.trapformat V2
```

You would run it like this, *changing the name of the text file appropriately*:

```bat
idrac6.bat IPList.txt username password UNKNOWN > idrac6732018.txt
```

*I've used `UNKNOWN` because there appears to be a `%4` argument which wasn't mentioned in your post, please insert it as required.*

**Edit**

You could also leave `idrac6.bat` untouched and run it with a command prompt line similar to this instead, *(obviously from the correct working directory)*:

```bat
(For /F "Delims=" %A In (IPList.txt) Do @Call idrac6.bat %A username password UNKNOWN)>idrac6732018.txt
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the help. Your command worked like a charm. I need your more help on this batch file, if the batch file can be modified to get the output in a detailed manner. The output i am getting now, do not have any information on what query the output is gathering data. I want that if a command for a server it running then below is the output. E.g as below:-

Comment: C:\windows\system32>racadm -r 10.64.201.139 -u hcladmin -p Ironm@n01 config -g cfgipmilan -o cfgipmilanalertenable 1
Security Alert: Certificate is invalid - Certificate is not signed by Trusted Third Party
Continuing execution. Use -S option for racadm to stop execution on certificate-related errors.

Object value modified successfully

Comment: C:\windows\system32>racadm -r 10.64.201.139 -u hcladmin -p Ironm@n01 config -g cfgIpmiLan -o cfgIpmiPetCommunityName WP!OME@Ro 
Security Alert: Certificate is invalid - Certificate is not signed by Trusted Third Party
Continuing execution. Use -S option for racadm to stop execution on certificate-related errors.

Object value modified successfully

Comment: C:\windows\system32>racadm -r 10.64.201.139 -u hcladmin -p Ironm@n01 eventfilters set -c idrac.alert.System.critical -a none -n snmp 
Security Alert: Certificate is invalid - Certificate is not signed by Trusted Third Party
Continuing execution. Use -S option for racadm to stop execution on certificate-related errors.     

ERROR: Invalid subcommand specified.

Comment: Hi Compo, Need this on urgent basis. Please help me here !!! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Unless I'm not understanding your issue correctly, it is my understanding that `config` only outputs errors, so you may be best advised to use `>idrac6732018.txt 2>&1` to capture those errors inside the same output file. Additionally removing `@Echo Off` or turning `Echo On` just before the commands in `idrac6.bat` would show each command just before its output in `idrac6732018.txt`. BTW, why not follow the advice and use the `-S` or even the `--nocertwarn` option.